# Ionic how to move an element to the right

Tags: css, ionic-framework, flexbox, ionic4

I have elements that I want to move to the right buts it't not working.

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>
    <ion-skeleton-text animated width="70%"></ion-skeleton-text>
    <ion-skeleton-text animated width="60%"></ion-skeleton-text>
  </ion-label>
  <ion-label slot="end">
    <ion-skeleton-text animated width="30%"></ion-skeleton-text>
    <ion-skeleton-text animated width="50%"></ion-skeleton-text>      
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

This display this.

[image]

Now those two ion skeleton text. I want to align/float those to the right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried setting `slot = "end"` to each of the ion-skeleton-text ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-label>
            <ion-skeleton-text animated width="70%"></ion-skeleton-text>
            <ion-skeleton-text animated width="60%"></ion-skeleton-text>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-label>
            <ion-skeleton-text animated width="30%"></ion-skeleton-text>
            <ion-skeleton-text animated width="50%"></ion-skeleton-text>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

You might need to play with the padding classes if this doesn't look quite right.

It uses an ion-grid to create two columns.